# Check every line a process outputs and do an action if a condition is met

Tags: bash, unix

I'm not so good with bash syntax and bash itself.
Basically, i want to check, in real time, while a process is creating output, if a certain line, with a certain content is printed, and if, do something.

```
    processName | while read myLine; if [ $myLine -eq "Loading X module" ]; then echo 'OMG' fi; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks ok, but you might get problem with buffering of the output.

Better make your `processName` think that it runs in a terminal. This can be achieved using a program called `unbuffer`:

```
unbuffer processName | while read myLine; if [ $myLine -eq "Loading X module" ]; then echo 'OMG' fi; done
```

Comment: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
That's why i've asked the question. But thanks for the unbuffer tip.

Answer (score 0):

Quote your variables:

```
if [ "$myLine" -eq "Loading X module" ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace this

```
if [ $myLine -eq "Loading X module" ];
```

with 
    if [ "$myLine" == "Loading X module" ];

The `-eq` operator is for integer comparison. And you should quote `$myLine` because it contains spaces causing the test expression not to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
processname | sed -n -e "/^Loading X Module$/p" | sed "s/^.*$/OMG/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, if your problem is "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'" then DO!

```
while read myLine; do if [ $myLine -eq "Loading X module" ]; then echo 'OMG' fi; done
```

You'll get more relevant answers if you post the error messages you're gettting.